# Creating a for loop from multiple links to create one table, using ESPN links for multiple seasons/years

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, lapply, rvest

I have the following links, successfully scraped, and I want to create a `for` loop. The table I am scraping is spread over 3 pages, thus the `whip_2018a`, `whip_2018b`, and `whip_2018c` link vectors:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

whip_2018a <- "http://www.espn.com/mlb/stats/pitching/_/order/false"
whip_2018b <- "http://www.espn.com/mlb/stats/pitching/_/count/41/qualified/true/order/false"
whip_2018c <- "http://www.espn.com/mlb/stats/pitching/_/count/81/qualified/true/order/false"
```

These links are the 2018 season, but I have links going back to 2005. **How can I turn the following code into a `for` loop that will consider multiple page links, and multiple years/seasons?**

```
# Scraping 2018 tables - there are multiple pages to the list
a2018 <- whip_2018a %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_node("#my-players-table > div > div.mod-content > table") %>%
  html_table(header = T)

b2018 <- whip_2018b %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_node("#my-players-table > div > div.mod-content > table") %>%
  html_table(header = T)

c2018 <- whip_2018c %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_node("#my-players-table > div > div.mod-content > table") %>%
  html_table(header = T)

# This creates the table for the 2018 season
whip_2018 <- rbind(a2018, b2018, c2018)
```

I understand if this is not possible, but my instinct says a few well-placed `[i]`'s could make this work. For reference, the 2017 links are here (most seasons are at least two or three links):

```
whip_2017a <- "http://www.espn.com/mlb/stats/pitching/_/year/2017/order/false"
whip_2017b <- "http://www.espn.com/mlb/stats/pitching/_/year/2017/count/41/qualified/true/order/false")
```

---

WHIP is an MLB statistic, hence my vector names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider generalizing your process in a defined function and pass in a year parameter. And to loop through function pass in a vector of years into an `lapply` for a list of dataframes to be concatenated at the end with `do.call(rbind, ...)` or `bind_rows`.

```
get_whip_data <- function(yr_param) {

    # ASSIGN URLS
    whip_a <- paste0("http://www.espn.com/mlb/stats/pitching/_/year/", yr_param, "/order/false")
    whip_b <- paste0("http://www.espn.com/mlb/stats/pitching/_/year/", yr_param, "/count/41/qualified/true/order/false")
    whip_c <- paste0("http://www.espn.com/mlb/stats/pitching/_/year/", yr_param, "/count/81/order/false")

    # BUILD DATA FRAMES
    a_data <- whip_a %>%
      read_html %>%
      html_node("#my-players-table > div > div.mod-content > table") %>%
      html_table(header = T)

    b_data <- whip_b %>%
      read_html %>%
      html_node("#my-players-table > div > div.mod-content > table") %>%
      html_table(header = T)

    c_data <- whip_c %>%
      read_html %>%
      html_node("#my-players-table > div > div.mod-content > table") %>%
      html_table(header = T)

    # APPEND ALL
    yr_df <- rbind(a_data, b_data, c_data)   # OR do.call(rbind, list(a_data, b_data, c_data))
    yr_df$year <- yr_param

    return(yr_df)
}

df_list <- lapply(2005:2017, get_whip_data)

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)       # REQUIRES SAME COLUMNS ACROSS YEARS
final_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(df_list)     # USE IF COLUMNS MAY DIFFER ACROSS YEARS
```

Should you have hard-coded links available, pass them in using `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`). This assumes all parameters are equal length where `Map` iterates elementwise.

```
get_whip_data <- function(yr_param, whip_a, whip_b, whip_c) {

    # BUILD DATA FRAMES
    a_data <- whip_a %>%
      read_html %>%
      html_node("#my-players-table > div > div.mod-content > table") %>%
      html_table(header = T)

    b_data <- whip_b %>%
      read_html %>%
      html_node("#my-players-table > div > div.mod-content > table") %>%
      html_table(header = T)

    c_data <- whip_c %>%
      read_html %>%
      html_node("#my-players-table > div > div.mod-content > table") %>%
      html_table(header = T)

    # APPEND ALL
    yr_df <- rbind(a_data, b_data, c_data)
    yr_df$year <- yr_param

    return(yr_df)
}

df_list <- Map(get_whip_data, years_vec, a_urls_vec, b_urls_vec, c_urls_vec)

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)       # REQUIRES SAME COLUMNS ACROSS YEARS
final_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(df_list)     # USE IF COLUMNS MAY DIFFER ACROSS YEARS
```

Comment: Can you define "hard-coded links?" Apologies - I'm not new in R, but R is pretty much the only language with which I have any fluency. Thanks!

Comment: OHHH, by "hard-coded links," do you mean if I have all of the links going back to 2005?

Comment: Yes. First solution dynamically creates URLs. Second solution reads in previously assigned URLs.

Comment: One other question - say I wanted to split the URL a few more times, like so: `paste0("http://www.espn.com/mlb/team/stats/", side, "/_/name/", team, "/year/", season, "/")` - every time I try and run it, I just get an error. I'm running it in a function like above, except picking out team, fielding/batting, and season

Comment: You need to pass those other vectors as additional arguments into `Map`, pasting together to build URL.

Comment: So essentially, I would have to hard-code my links? Or I can I use the `Map` wrapper in conjunction with the first example above? This is cool - thank you

Comment: We may be edging on another question. You can use `expand.grid()` to create all combinations of *side*, *team*, and *season* into a dataframe and then pass those dataframe columns into `Map` call.

Comment: If you want to take stab at it, I put it in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51428757/scraping-a-url-with-multiple-parameters-passed-through-said-url?noredirect=1&lq=1 - no worries if you don't have time, but if you do, don't worry about the tables, etc, I'm just curious about how to parse the url!

Comment: But seriously, no worries at all if you don't have time! I appreciate the help you've given already